# Visual Studio 2022 no reconoce errores en vistas cshtml

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor, cshtml

estoy teniendo un problema con VisualStudio 2022 desde hace ya varios días. El detalle es que parece que no me esta detectando los errores de Razor dentro de las visas (.cshtml) no me marca variables inexistentes o de referencias.

Por ejemplo, puedo escribir en el archivo .cshtml vacío lo siguiente:

```
@{
 var MyNumber = 1;
 mynumber = 3
}
```

VisualStudio2022 no me reconoce ni me marca que mynumber no existe, simplemente lo deja ahí en blanco y truena cuando se ejecuta la pagina.

Y el detalle es que en la versión VisualStudio2017 no tengo este problema. Adjunto dos imágenes de ejemplo:

VS2022:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

VS2017:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad es que me esta causando muchos problemas ultimamente.

Me gustaría saber si alguien se haya enfrentado a este problema y lo ha resuelto, ya he estado siguiendo instrucciones haciendo búsquedas en otros foros, pero ninguna me ha funcionado, entre ellas borrar la carpeta .vs en los proyectos, borrar el .suo , borrar caches e incluso eh desinstalado y vuelto a instalar VisualStudio2022 ya 4 veces.

Esto solo me sucede en las vistas, en el resto del proyecto todo normal sin problemas. Seria genial si alguien tuviera la solución.

Comment: Verifica que tienes los componentes o cargas de trabajo necesarios. También recuerda que el editor todavía es nuevo y puede tener errores.

Comment: Gracias ya verifique con mis compa;eros de trabajo y tenemos los mismos componentes eh incluso calando con configuraciones iguales. Lo curioso es que solo me sucede a mi. Bueno, igual gracias por aportar.

Comment: En esta pregunta dicen que ya se lanzo un fix para ese issue:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/intellisense-in-razor-files-cshtml-is-not-working-1/1517714